# Enabling UIButton in TableViewCell enables in more Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `TableViewController` with my customed `TableViewCell`, on each row there are two buttons, one is hidden the other is not, when I tap the shown button I want to show the other button, I´ve covered this, my problem is, if I scroll down other hidden buttons are showed because of the Reuseidentifier.

What can I do to only show up the button from the row I`ve selected.

Hope I got clear if not please ask me.

Thank you all.

Comment: Disable the button in the `prepareForReuse` method of your cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll the tableView remaining buttons are hidden because you wrote setHidden method in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Without putting any condition so take one NSMutableArray and allocate memory to it. Whatever the index you select just add it MutableArray.Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Put one condition if that array contains the indexPath don't hide else hide the button.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  CutomTableView *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.show setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.show addTarget:self action:@selector(showButtonACtion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
//self.selectedRow is NSMutable Array
   if ([self.selectedRow containsObject:selectedIndexPath]) {
        [cell.hideBtn setHidden:NO];
    }else{
        [cell.hideBtn setHidden:YES];
    }
    return cell;
}
-(void)showButtonACtion:(UIButton*)sender{
   NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
    [self.selectedRow addObject:myIP];
     [self.tableV reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rubiya I´ll give a try on that. I´ll let you how is ends.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on particular button to show another button, just save that NSIndexpath.

For example,
If you are click on 2nd row, then add value in NSMutableDicionary as

```
[mutableDict setValue:@"YES" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath.row]];
```

And then check for particular indexPath in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Whenever you find @"YES" for particular row, implement your desired logic to show or hide buttons.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you Dhruvik, but the button is handled in the TableViewCell.m, I mean the action in catched here, how could I send the NSMutableDictionary info filled in TableViewCell to TableViewController for handle it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method you told me?

Comment: for that you can implement delegate to achieve this. @TonyM.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)firstButton:(UIControl *)sender
{
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
       [cell.button2 setHidden:NO];.
}
```